# How can I call a function from inside another class and use it in a new file?

Tags: python

I am trying to make it so I can call paddle_up and paddle_down in the second file but I can only get the function "move".

```
class PaddleOne(Turtle):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.segments = [0]
        self.head = self.segments[0]
        self.Paddle_One()

    def Paddle_One(self):
        self.move()
        self.penup()
        self.color("white")
        self.shape("square")
        self.shapesize(stretch_wid=5, stretch_len=1)
        self.goto(x=350, y=0)
        self.head = self.segments[0]

    def move(self):
        # moving the paddle:
        def paddle_up():
            new_y = self.ycor() + 20
            self.goto(self.xcor(), new_y)

        def paddle_down():
            new_y = self.ycor() - 20
            self.goto(self.xcor(), new_y)
```

This is the second file that I am trying to use the functions paddle_up and paddle_down however when I run the code I get the error message "AttributeError: type object 'PaddleOne' has no attribute 'paddle_up'".

```
from turtle import Screen
from UserPaddles import PaddleOne as PO
import time

# screen creation:
screen = Screen()
paddle = PO()

# screen setting:
screen.title("Pong Game")
screen.setup(width=800, height=600)
screen.bgcolor("black")

# key presses:
screen.listen()
screen.onkey(PO().paddle_up(), "w")
screen.onkey(PO().paddle_down(), "s")
```

I've looked for the answer elsewhere but no one seems to have the exact issue of calling a function within a function.

Comment: Please ask the question you actually have. If the problem is that there is an error message you don't understand, after you have taken the obvious steps to perform a task, don't ask "how do I perform the task?". Instead, first try to **read and understand** the error, and then ask either "why does this error occur?" or "how can I fix this error?" as appropriate.

Comment: Anyway, the problem is that it does not make any sense to organize the code this way. What **problem do you hope to solve** by nesting functions? What is the **intended purpose** of `move`?

Comment: Just so I can call them through the same function. I asked my question and have had two answers so no need for your help. Including an error message is only there to make it more clear the issue I'm having with my code.

Comment: Furthermore, I understood why the error was there I was just curious whether there was a way I could use one function. Read the question

Comment: "Just so I can call them through the same function." I can't understand what this means. What do you want the code to look like, when you call it? What should happen when that code runs? Why?

Comment: Literally, look at the answers they were all able to understand what I was trying to do but they explained that I couldn't because it should've only been used to describe my issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Get rid of the move (don't think you need it), and then PaddleOne will have accessible attributes paddle_up & paddle_down

```
class PaddleOne(Turtle):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.segments = [0]
        self.head = self.segments[0]
        self.Paddle_One()

    def Paddle_One(self):
        self.move()
        self.penup()
        self.color("white")
        self.shape("square")
        self.shapesize(stretch_wid=5, stretch_len=1)
        self.goto(x=350, y=0)
        self.head = self.segments[0]

  
  # moving the paddle:
  def paddle_up(self):
        new_y = self.ycor() + 20
        self.goto(self.xcor(), new_y)

  def paddle_down():
       new_y = self.ycor() - 20
       self.goto(self.xcor(), new_y)
```

Answer (score 0):

paddle_up and paddle_down were scoped under the move() function but you are calling as instance. Just make paddle_Up and paddle_down instance functions

```
class PaddleOne(Turtle):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.segments = [0]
        self.head = self.segments[0]
        self.Paddle_One()

    def Paddle_One(self):
        self.move()
        self.penup()
        self.color("white")
        self.shape("square")
        self.shapesize(stretch_wid=5, stretch_len=1)
        self.goto(x=350, y=0)
        self.head = self.segments[0]


    def paddle_up(self):
        new_y = self.ycor() + 20
        self.goto(self.xcor(), new_y)

    def paddle_down(self):
        new_y = self.ycor() - 20
        self.goto(self.xcor(), new_y)
```

Comment: I thought about doing this but I would have to call them separately when using them again. Is there not another way I could do it?

Comment: "but I would have to call them separately when using them again" I can't understand what this is supposed to mean. If you want two things to happen when you call a function, then just write a function that does both things. But it doesn't make any sense to do both of these things at once anyway; what would be the point of moving the paddle up and then immediately moving it back down?

Comment: Not what I intended to mean. I meant to say that I wanted them to be in one function to be easily identified in the code not for them to happen at the same time because as you said there would be no point haha.

Comment: Functions are not a tool for storing things (including other functions); they're a tool for *describing a sequence of actions to take*.

Comment: Okay! Thanks you for explaining it!